# Returning object from webservice via controller class returns an empty object

Tags: c#, web-services, object, guid

I'm building my objects with data from my database and so far so good

```
    public static List<ImageData> GetAllImageData(Guid UserId)
    {
        List<ImageData> imageDataList = new List<ImageData>();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = DBHandler.getCommand("sp_Get_AllImagesForWebUser");
            DBHandler.AddParameter(ref cmd, "@UserId", UserId);
            foreach (DataRow row in DBHandler.ExecuteSP(cmd).Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                LogWriter.Print("imagedatacontroller() new Guid(row[ImageId].ToString()): " + new Guid(row["ImageId"].ToString()), LogLevel.DEBUG);
                imageDataList.Add(
                    new ImageData(new Guid(row["ImageId"].ToString()), new Guid(row["UserId"].ToString()), row["ImagePath"].ToString(), (int)row["PatientId"], row["BodyPart"].ToString(), row["ReasonForVisit"].ToString(), row["Diagnosis"].ToString(), Convert.ToBoolean(row["ConsentForResearch"]), Convert.ToBoolean(row["ConsentForEducation"]), Convert.ToBoolean(row["ConsentForStorage"]))
                    );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogWriter.Print("Exception: ImageDataController->GetAllImageData() " + e, LogLevel.EXCEPTION);
        }
        return imageDataList;
    }
```

Then I have a webservice (.ASMX) that exposes the function and returns the List of ImageData

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<ImageData> GetImageDataFromUser(string UserId)
    {
        return ImageDataController.GetAllImageData(new Guid(UserId));
    }
```

But the problem is that the two Guid attributes of ImageData (ImageId and UserId) is a only-zero value Guid and I can't figure out why. I've validated with my LogWriter that its a valid and the correct Guid, but as soon as I try and expose it through my webservice its a only-zero guid.

This is how my SOAP looks like

```
<ArrayOfImageData xmlns="http://172.18.67.166:147/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    <ImageData> 
        <ImageId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ImageId> 
        <UserId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</UserId> 
        <ImagePath>C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Omegapoint\data\UploadedImages\0416f1aa-9b57-4ba8-be54-398ffa9d7139.PNG</ImagePath> 
        <PatientId>0</PatientId> 
        <CreationDate>2013-03-17T22:08:10.1964107+01:00</CreationDate> 
        <Bodypart/> 
        <ReasonForVisit/> 
        <Diagnosis/> 
        <ConsentForResearch>false</ConsentForResearch> 
        <ConsentForEducation>false</ConsentForEducation>
        <ConsentForStorage>false</ConsentForStorage> 
    </ImageData>
</ArrayOfImageData>
```

But the ImageId should be:

```
0416f1aa-9b57-4ba8-be54-398ffa9d7139
```

And the UserId should be:

```
4bcd23a9-2815-42ef-b9ea-671b2aa08aa3
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: can you post the raw guids from the database as well as what the guids look like prior to being returned from the GetAllImageData method?

Comment: Do you want JSON, or XML, to be returned from the service? If you're looking for XML, then remove that ScriptMethod attribute.

Comment: Also, ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: As for the ASMX vs WCF it wasn't my call. And I want to return a JSON format as I find them easier to work with in my JavaScript/AJAX calls.

I still haven't gotten it to work, even if I change the datatype from Guid to string, and it didn't work with adding XmlAttribute to my Guid variables, and it wasnt a problem between my Controller class and the Webservice (because if I placed the database call inside the webservice I got the same result).

I got it working with a very ugly hack, so if somebody got a solution please share.